# Tuleap - LDAP Plugin - Active Directory Issues

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tuleap

I've used the instructions from the tuleap documentation (http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administration-guide/services.html#ldap) to install the LDAP/Active Directory plugin and configure it, however we still can't login with the accounts that are listed in Active Directory source.

Here is my ldap.inc

```
<?php
$sys_ldap_server = "[FQDN of Domain Controller]";
$sys_ldap_server_type = "ActiveDirectory";
$sys_ldap_dn     = "DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = "CN=[USERNAME],OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = "[PASSWORD]";
$sys_ldap_uid   = "sAMAccountName";
$sys_ldap_eduid = "sAMAccountName";
$sys_ldap_cn    = "cn";
$sys_ldap_mail  = "mail";
$sys_ldap_people_dn     = "OU=xx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
$sys_ldap_search_user="(|(sAMAccountName=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))";
$sys_ldap_tooltip_search_user='(&(|(sn=%words%*)(givenName=%words%*)(uid=%words%*))(!(givenName=BoiteVocale))(uid=*))';
$sys_ldap_tooltip_search_attrs='uid;sn;givenName';
$sys_ldap_default_user_status = "A";
$sys_ldap_svn_auth = "0";
$sys_ldap_daily_sync = "1";
$sys_ldap_daily_sync_retention_period = "1";
$sys_ldap_user_management = "1";
$sys_ldap_grp_enabled   = "1";
$sys_ldap_grp_dn        = "OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
$sys_ldap_grp_cn        = "cn";
$sys_ldap_grp_uid       = "sAMAccountName";
$sys_ldap_grp_member    = "member";
$sys_ldap_threshold_users_suspension = "";
?>
```

I have installed the ldapsearch package from yum and performed the following command which returned a successful report of the user from the server

```
ldapsearch -x -h "[FQDN of Domain Controller]" -LLL -D "CN=[USERNAME],OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" -w "[PASSWORD]" -b "OU=xx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" "sAMAccountName=[Username to search]"
```

Port 389 is open and listed for full ALLOW within the iptables.
Tuleap version 8.19.99.15.

Any help would be greatly appreciated with allowing Active Directory users to authenticate to Tuleap.

As well as that, can someone please answer the following:

1. Is there any log that can help me to find where is the problem ?
2. If I have a local user with the same login than in Active Directory, what will happen ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should get more informations about what Tuleap does with your Active Directory in `/var/log/tuleap/codendi_syslog`, you might need to set the logs to be more verbose (go to `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc` and change `sys_log_level`).

If you have a local account whose login is equal to some AD `sAMAccountName`, when the AD guy will connect it will get a new, different, account with _2 as suffix 'bob_morris_2' for instance.

You can link manually local and AD accounts directly in the DB by setting the `sAMAccountName` value in `ldap_id` column of users DB.

Comment: Thanks for that info, log contents are:

`2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [debug] Ignoring statistics queue.
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [debug] Ignoring fts queue.
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [debug] Processing default queue as root user.
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [info] Restore ownership to /var/tmp/tuleap_cache
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [info] Restore ownership to /var/tmp/tuleap_cache/lang
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [info] Restore ownership to /var/tmp/tuleap_cache/hooks.json
2016-09-27T06:15:02+02:00 [debug] Processing default queue as app user.`

AD still not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is LDAP plugin active in plugin administration (web site admin) +  `$sys_auth_type` set to `ldap` ? you should have something like `2016-09-27T02:10:02+02:00 [debug] Bound to LDAP server: ldap://ldap` in the logs when there is an attempt to login